# Can I use the Z-score and its associated p-value in this context?

Tags: z-score

I'm looking to specific genetic events in a genome-wide manner. I've more than 100,000 events distributed along the human genome and want to know if some genomic regions have more genetic events than random. What I did: I divided the genome in non-overlapping 100,000bp long region and counted how many genetic events I found for each one of them. After analysis I've ~30,000 non-overlapping 100kb regions with its associated of genetic event number. Now to compute a p-value I was thinking to use a z-score such as :

```
# region dataframe
chr   start  end    geneticEvent
chr1  0      100000 7
chr1  100000 200000 3
chr1  200000 300000 34
.etc..

zscore <- scale(region$geneticEvent)
pvalue <- pnorm(-zscore)
padj <- p.adjust(pvalue,"fdr")
```

Is this ok to do that ?

Edit > Here's the genetic event distribution (mean=2.754452 ; sd=6.561196)
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide a plot of geneticEvents? I mean, ```plot(density(df$geneticEvent))``` Most probably, you have well-established discrete distribution (Poisson or NB). As for Z-scores - you can do whatever you want on your data, however, the performance will be poor (your distribution is skewed for sure).

Answer (score 0):

P-value calculation based on normal distribution assumption is more or less correct (I mean useful) only for normal-like distributions. Here you can see that you distribution is not even close to normal. Try to fit other distributions and calculate p-value based on inversed fitted cdf. You should look for discrete distributions for fitting. I bet you have "zero-inflated smth" here (beta binomial? hypergeometric?). Try to change your window size: it may help you to establish a true parametric family of distributions.